# How do I create and reference dictionaries that are the values within a dictionary dynamically?

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

I would like to end up with something like this:

```
directory = {  'root' : {'parent': 'none',  'children': ['folder1','folder2']},
            'folder1': {'parent': 'root',  'children': ['folder3']},
            'folder2': {'parent': 'root',  'children': []},
            'folder3': {'parent': 'folder1', 'children': []} }
```

but without explicitly defining it in my code.  If I try to build it from within the code like this:

```
mydirectory = {}

my_key = 'root'
my_value = {}
mydirectory[my_key] = my_value

inner_key = 'parent'
inner_value = 'none'
mydirectory[my_key][my_value][inner_key] = inner_value

print(mydirectory)
```

I get a *TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'* on the next to last line and I am lost how to build (and reference) this dynamically. (Realistically all of the values like 'folder1' would be taken from a list and referenced like outerlist[2], i.e. my_key = outerlist[2].)

Additionally, how to both *create* and *reference* a list like ['folder1', 'folder2'] for the value of the key 'children' in the first key:value pair?

Comment: `mydirectory[my_key]` is already the same as `my_value` (after the assignment). So the second to last line should be `mydirectory[my_key][inner_key] = inner_value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line `mydirectory[my_key] = my_value`, your dictionary looks like `{'root': {}}`.

The line `mydirectory[my_key][my_value]...` will throw `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` because `mydirectory[my_key]` is a dictionary, and `my_value` is also a dictionary – dictionaries and other mutable types like lists cannot be keys for a dictionary – instead you only need to modify `mydirectory[my_key]`:

```
mydirectory[my_key][inner_key] = inner_value
```

Result:

```
{'root': {'parent': 'none'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in the line before the last line,

```
mydirectory[my_key][my_value][inner_key] = inner_value
```

You are trying to use `my_value` as the key in the dictionary which is not allowed as mutable types cannot be a key in dictionary.

So just remove `my_value` as a key in that line.

```
mydirectory[my_key][inner_key] = inner_value
```